# How can i launch a new .py file from a python script

Tags: python, authentication

I would like to launch a seperate .py program from my script. If the user successfully logged in then the new window should open. Inside this if statement.

```
if logged_in==True:
```

Comment: Have you tried using `import`?

Comment: Care to mention what you have tried to do thus far?

Comment: I havent tried anything because i would have no clue how-relatively new to python-how would i go about using import to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the path to the python executable from the `sys` module and run programs using the `subprocess` module. There are several ways to run programs, but a simple one is `call`, which waits for the program to terminate.

```
import sys
import subprocess as subp

if logged_in == True:
    subp.call([sys.executable, "someprogram.py", "arg1", "arg2"])
```